# Sync task updates in a Google Site with Calendar

Tags: google-calendar, google-classic-sites, google-tasks, synchronization

Is it possible, after modifying a task (mainly the date) in the tasks list in a Google Site, for the information to sync and update with a Google Calendar?

I have a task tracker in a Google Site and want to know if I update the details of a task that it can also update it on the calendar or on any Google calendar.

Comment: I don't know of anyway of syncing a Google Site list, are there any dedicated to-do list service that comes with an embeddable gadget you could put on the site and the Google Calendar sync function you are after? Remember The Milk or Toodledo maybe?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could do this using [Google Apps Script](http://www.readwriteweb.com/enterprise/2010/10/google-apps-scripts.php) to update the Google Calendar when the change happens on the Google Site. This is probably more complex than what you were looking for but I don't believe there is any way to do this without writing a custom script.

Some information on the Calendar and Sites services API:

- [Calendar Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_calendar)
- [Sites Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_sites)